# How can I find keywords in a text file or in a variable?

Tags: rust

I'd like to find a keyword in a text file or in a variable. I want to get user input and paste it into a text file.

my code:

```
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let mut user_name = String::new();
    println!("Hello what is your name: ");
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut name).unwrap();
    fs::write("files/user_name.txt", user_name).unwrap();

    let mut user_wish = String::new();
    println!("What is your wish: ");
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut user_wish).unwrap();
    fs::write("files/user_wish.txt", user_wish).unwrap();
}
```

I don't know how to find keywords like `my` and `name` in the text file **user_wish.txt** so that I can list `user_name`.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.contains ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rust
use std::fs;

static KEYWORDS: &'static [&'static str] = &["my", "name"];

fn main() {
    let mut user_name = String::new();
    println!("Hello what is your name: ");
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut user_name).unwrap();

    // ---
    // fs::write<P, C>(path: P, contents: C)
    // -- Note contents takes ownership of `C` / `user_clone`
    // that memory will be consumed after it finishes
    // so we give it clone(), so we can still access `user_name`
    fs::write("files/user_name.txt", user_name.clone()).unwrap();

    for kword in KEYWORDS {
        if user_name.contains(kword) {
            println!("contains keyword");
        }
    }

    let mut user_wish = String::new();
    println!("What is your wish: ");
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut user_wish).unwrap();
    fs::write("files/user_wish.txt", user_wish).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Answers that are just code blocks are substantially less useful than answers that mix code and prose. Explain what the code is doing, why it's doing it that way, advantages/disadvantages, tradeoffs, how the OP could have figured this out themselves, etc.

Comment: @Shepmaster I added some comments, I think his problem was with the ownership since it consumed the value. Tried displaying that when a function takes ownership. Feel free to edit anything else in you see appropriate.

Comment: *I think his problem was with* — instead of guessing you could (a) add a comment requesting clarification, (b) downvote the question because it's unclear, or (c) vote to close it as being unclear (or a combination of the three).